# Why does this decorator program produce an unexpected output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have written the following program to provide wrappers (decorators) to the two functions `price_report` and `sales_report`. I have just assigned the wrappers to these functions (last two lines in the code below) without explicitly invoking `price_report()` or `sales_report()`. But the code produces the output shown further below. How come?

In fact, if I make explicit call to `price_report()`, I get the error message `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.

```
# wrapper.py

def wrapper(report):
    def head_and_foot(report):
        print(report.__name__)
        report()
        print("End of", report.__name__, "\n\n")
    return head_and_foot(report)

def price_report():
    cars  = ['Celerio', 'i10', 'Amaze', 'Figo']
    price = [500_000, 350_000, 800_000, 550_000]
    for x, y in zip(cars, price):
        print(f'{x:8s}', f'{y:8,d}')

def sales_report():
    cars  = ['Celerio', 'i10', 'Amaze', 'Figo']
    units = [5000, 3000, 1000, 800]
    for x, y in zip(cars, units):
        print(f'{x:8s}', f'{y:8,d}')

sales_report = wrapper(sales_report)
price_report = wrapper(price_report)
```

Output of the above program (whether run inside Jupyter notebook or from the command line as `python wrapper.py`):

```
sales_report
Celerio     5,000
i10         3,000
Amaze       1,000
Figo          800
End of sales_report


price_report
Celerio   500,000
i10       350,000
Amaze     800,000
Figo      550,000
End of price_report
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's harder than it needs to be to see exactly what's going on with your code, because you've chosen confusing names in writing your decorator. Here's a version that does exactly the same thing as your code, with the names changed:

```
def head_and_foot(func):
    def wrapper(func):
        print(func.__name__)
        func()
        print("End of", func.__name__, "\n\n")
    return wrapper(func)

def price_report():
    cars  = ['Celerio', 'i10', 'Amaze', 'Figo']
    price = [500_000, 350_000, 800_000, 550_000]
    for x, y in zip(cars, price):
        print(f'{x:8s}', f'{y:8,d}')

def sales_report():
    cars  = ['Celerio', 'i10', 'Amaze', 'Figo']
    units = [5000, 3000, 1000, 800]
    for x, y in zip(cars, units):
        print(f'{x:8s}', f'{y:8,d}')

sales_report = head_and_foot(sales_report)
price_report = head_and_foot(price_report)
```

There are three changes here:

- `wrapper` → `head_and_foot`
- `head_and_foot` → `wrapper`
- `report` → `func`

The function you called `wrapper`, which I've renamed to `head_and_foot`, is a *decorator*. What that means is that it accepts a function as an argument, and returns another function which is meant to replace the one it accepted.

Normally, the replacement function it returns is a *wrapper* for the original function, which means that it does the same thing the original function does, wrapped in some extra actions.

To keep all this straight, it's conventional to call the decorator by a name describing its effect (e.g. `head_and_foot`, call the function it accepts `func`, and call the wrapper it returns `wrapper`. That's what I've done above.

Once you've got sensible names, it's a little easier to see that you have two problems:

1. `wrapper` is supposed to be a replacement for the functions being decorated, so it should have the same *signature* – meaning that it should take the same number and type of arguments. Your functions `price_report` and `sales_report` don't take any arguments at all (i.e. there's nothing between the parentheses `()` in their `def` statement), but `wrapper` takes the function it's supposed to replace as an argument, which makes no sense at all.

   That line should just be `def wrapper():` to match the signature of the functions being replaced.
2. A decorator is supposed to return a replacement function, but your decorator is *calling* the replacement and returning the result. Instead of `return wrapper(func)`, you just need `return wrapper`.

After making both those changes, we end up with this:

```
def head_and_foot(func):
    def wrapper():
        print(func.__name__)
        func()
        print("End of", func.__name__, "\n\n")
    return wrapper

def price_report():
    cars  = ['Celerio', 'i10', 'Amaze', 'Figo']
    price = [500_000, 350_000, 800_000, 550_000]
    for x, y in zip(cars, price):
        print(f'{x:8s}', f'{y:8,d}')

def sales_report():
    cars  = ['Celerio', 'i10', 'Amaze', 'Figo']
    units = [5000, 3000, 1000, 800]
    for x, y in zip(cars, units):
        print(f'{x:8s}', f'{y:8,d}')

sales_report = head_and_foot(sales_report)
price_report = head_and_foot(price_report)
```

When we run this fixed code, we don't get any unexpected output, but we do get two functions that do what we expect:

```
>>> price_report()
price_report
Celerio   500,000
i10       350,000
Amaze     800,000
Figo      550,000
End of price_report 


>>> sales_report()
sales_report
Celerio     5,000
i10         3,000
Amaze       1,000
Figo          800
End of sales_report
```

Comment: I have book marked at least 10 different articles on Decorators, but none of them mentioned the two points on naming convention and what needs to be returned so explicitly. Not just two cents, but two millions. I confess that my commonsense took a French leave, when I conceived and composed this code.